# VPS сервер выдаёт 404. React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vps, развертывание

Я сосвсем чайник в вопросе, но я очень хочу задеплоить свою работу.

Есть приложение в стеке MERN. (mongo, express, react, node)

Есть VPS сервер на ubuntu который я настроил по короткой инструкции c использованием nginx:
https://github.com/yestellar/deploy-node-nginx-ssl

Сервер предоставялет Jino.

В корневом каталоге у меня 2 папки: client и server, туда я собственно склонировал нужные репозитории. В папке сервера склонировал node сервер и запустил, в консоле вывелось сообщение о том, что всё ок. Далее с помощью pm2 запустил client командами из статьи по ссылке выше.

`NODE_ENV=production pm2 start npm --name strapi -- run start # Запустить в режиме продакшн npm run start скрипт и назвать "strapi"`

Статус показывает "ок"

В целом везде, все статусы ок: nginx, node, npm, mongo...но сайт выдаёт 404.

Пробовал разные настроки и проксирование в `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`  но это не дало результатов

Как исправить? За любую информацию буду очень благодарен

Вот код `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` :

P.S.Строки с return закоментил т.к. бесконечный редирект, сначала надо что бы хоть http заработал, а с https потом разберусь.

```
server {
   # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name site-name.ru  www.site-name.ru;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
}

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):

            #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            #}
    
            # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
            # concurs with nginx's one
            #
            #location ~ /\.ht {
            #       deny all;
            #}
    
        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site-name.ru/fullchain.pem; # man>
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site-name.ru/privkey.pem; # m>
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    
    
    }
    
    #
    #server {
    #       listen 80;
    #       listen [::]:80;
    #
    #       server_name example.com;
    #
    #       root /var/www/example.com;
    #       index index.html;
    #
    #       location / {
    #               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    #       }
    #}
    
    server {
        if ($host = www.site-name.ru) {
           # return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot
    
    
        if ($host = site-name.ru) {
            #return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot
    
    
            listen 80 default_server;
            listen [::]:80 default_server;
    
            server_name site-name.ru www.site-name.ru;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
    }
```

Comment: В error_log nginx'а что-нибудь пишется?

Comment: Я добавил файл /etc/nginx/sites-available/default в описании, и как видите в конце есть return 404. Я попробовал закоментить его. После чего я не получаю 404, но получаю просто страницу приветствия nginx, которая говорит, что всё ок, но надо настроить. Как теперь мне сделать вывод моего приложения? В dev версии на своем компьютере я просто обращался к localhost:3000

Comment: А в /var/log/nginx/error.log что содержится?

Comment: Последние ошибки были зарегестрированы вчера(видимо когда пробовал разные прокси). Сейчас в логах ошибок нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена.
Я нашёл ответ на свой вопрос в документации к nginx вот тут:
http://nginx.org/ru/docs/beginners_guide.html

Как можно видеть в моём файле `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

есть блоки вида `server { ... }`.

В каждом таком блоке есть слушатель портов `listen`, а так же `location`

Проблема была в том, что во втором блоке `server` где стоит стандартный `listen 80` не был обозначен location. Как только я его обозначил, сервер начал выдавать моё приложение